# Calling methods in non-assembly (non-managed) dlls through reflection in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, late-binding

I want to use reflection to dynamically call a dll (not an assembly, non-managed, possibly COM object model) in vb.net.

I've seen several different methods of calling a method in a dll that is a .net assembly - but I have not found the way to dynamically call a method inside of a dll like user32.dll or winmm.dll. I believe this would be called late-binding?

The reason I'm asking is because I am building a language that will depend on external libraries for lots of different functionality.

An example (in this language I'm building):

```
Declare Function mciSendStringA using "winmm.dll" (strCommand As String, strReturn As String, returnLength As Integer, blah As Integer) As Integer

Declare Function WriteConsoleA using "kernel32.dll" (hConsoleOutput As Integer, lpBuffer As String, numberofcharstowrite as Integer, lpReserved as Integer) As Boolean
```

When I build the interpreter for the call to mciSendString in winmm.dll, how can I use reflection to handle this? I want the user to be able to reference any dll/method they wish.

Can I get some guidance in the right direction? Perhaps even some vb.net code that I can take apart and understand?

Comment: Avoid trying to implement your own pinvoke marshaller, the details will eat you.  TypeBuilder.DefinePInvokeMethod() is instrumental.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use reflection on unmanaged Win32 native libraries.

Instead, you load them and retrieve pointers to unmanaged functions to call them by address. This is how to do this in C#:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx

Comment: It would be better to wrap the module handle as a `SafeHandle` type (instead of `IntPtr`) and have `ReleaseHandle` call `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: In fact, this article shows an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163716.aspx

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I've converted the C# code presented in that article to vb.net and it works pretty well.